# Xcode 13.2.1 crashes while uploading archive

Tags: xcode

When I want to submit app to AppStore, after passing wizard steps (checkboxes and etc.), at the beginning of uploading archive, it crashes.

- I tried it number of times. After restarting Xcode, macOS, and it happened again.
- I tried it with another app (a testing app) and it happened again.
- I updated macOS from 12.2 to 12.3, and it happened again.

Xcode: 13.2.1
macOS: 12.3 (and 12.2)

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               Xcode [8137]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               13.2.1 (19586)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-19586000000000000~2 (13C100)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2022-03-24 11:11:03.6454 +0430
OS Version:            macOS 12.3 (21E230)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     3.0 (14Y910)
Anonymous UUID:        27CEBE33-9C74-9153-A5E8-51C4385EE3C7


Time Awake Since Boot: 1000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        10  Dispatch queue: ConcurrentQueue: -[IDEDistributionSummaryStepViewController viewDidLoad]_block_invoke

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION (NSInvalidArgumentException): *** -[__NSCFCalendar rangeOfUnit:startDate:interval:forDate:]: date cannot be nil
UserInfo: (null)
Open FDs: 64/9472
Hints:
0: Calling block provided by:
0   DVTDispatchAsync (in DVTFoundation)
1   -[IDEDistributionSummaryStepViewController viewDidLoad] (in IDEKit)
2   -[NSViewController _sendViewDidLoad] (in AppKit)
3   -[NSViewController _loadViewIfRequired] (in AppKit)
4   -[NSViewController view] (in AppKit)
5   -[DVTViewController view] (in DVTViewControllerKit)
6   -[IDEDistributionAssistantWindowController setDistributionStepViewController:] (in IDEKit)
7   -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKeys:count:maybeOldValuesDict:maybeNewValuesDict:usingBlock:] (in Foundation)
8   -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKey:key:key:usingBlock:] (in Foundation)
9   _NSSetObjectValueAndNotify (in Foundation)
10   -[IDEDistributionAssistantWindowController next:] (in IDEKit)
11   -[IDEDistributionPackagingStepViewController _pipelineSucceeded] (in IDEKit)
12   __58-[IDEDistributionPackagingStepViewController _runPipeline]_block_invoke.70 (in IDEKit)
13   __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ (in DVTFoundation)
14   ___DVTAsyncPerformBlockOnMainRunLoop_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
15   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ (in CoreFoundation)
16   __CFRunLoopDoBlocks (in CoreFoundation)
17   __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
18   CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
19   RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
20   ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
21   _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter (in HIToolbox)
22   _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
23   -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
24   -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in DVTKit)
25   -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
26   -[DVTApplication run] (in DVTKit)
27   NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
28   start (in dyld)
Backtrace:
0   __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
1   DVTFailureHintExceptionPreprocessor (in DVTFoundation)
2   objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
3   -[__NSCFCalendar rangeOfUnit:startDate:interval:forDate:] (in CoreFoundation)
4   -[_NSCopyOnWriteCalendarWrapper rangeOfUnit:startDate:interval:forDate:] (in CoreFoundation)
5   -[IDEDistributionItemSummaryNode(KitAdditions) expirationWarningStringIfNeeded:resourceTypeName:] (in IDEKit)
6   -[IDEDistributionItemSummaryNode(KitAdditions) preload] (in IDEKit)
7   __55-[IDEDistributionSummaryStepViewController viewDidLoad]_block_invoke_2 (in IDEKit)
8   __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ (in DVTFoundation)
9   __DVTDispatchAsync_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
10   _dispatch_call_block_and_release (in libdispatch.dylib)
11   _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib)
12   _dispatch_continuation_pop (in libdispatch.dylib)
13   _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke (in libdispatch.dylib)
14   _dispatch_root_queue_drain (in libdispatch.dylib)
15   _dispatch_worker_thread2 (in libdispatch.dylib)
16   _pthread_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
17   start_wqthread (in libsystem_pthread.dylib)
Possibly stale failure hints from 2022-03-24 06:41:03 +0000:
0: Calling block provided by:
0   DVTDispatchAsync (in DVTFoundation)
1   -[IDEDistributionSummaryStepViewController viewDidLoad] (in IDEKit)
2   -[NSViewController _sendViewDidLoad] (in AppKit)
3   -[NSViewController _loadViewIfRequired] (in AppKit)
4   -[NSViewController view] (in AppKit)
5   -[DVTViewController view] (in DVTViewControllerKit)
6   -[IDEDistributionAssistantWindowController setDistributionStepViewController:] (in IDEKit)
7   -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKeys:count:maybeOldValuesDict:maybeNewValuesDict:usingBlock:] (in Foundation)
8   -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKey:key:key:usingBlock:] (in Foundation)
9   _NSSetObjectValueAndNotify (in Foundation)
10   -[IDEDistributionAssistantWindowController next:] (in IDEKit)
11   -[IDEDistributionPackagingStepViewController _pipelineSucceeded] (in IDEKit)
12   __58-[IDEDistributionPackagingStepViewController _runPipeline]_block_invoke.70 (in IDEKit)
13   __DVT_CALLING_CLIENT_BLOCK__ (in DVTFoundation)
14   ___DVTAsyncPerformBlockOnMainRunLoop_block_invoke (in DVTFoundation)
15   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ (in CoreFoundation)
16   __CFRunLoopDoBlocks (in CoreFoundation)
17   __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
18   CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
19   RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
20   ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
21   _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter (in HIToolbox)
22   _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
23   -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
24   -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in DVTKit)
25   -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
26   -[DVTApplication run] (in DVTKit)
27   NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
28   start (in dyld)
ProductBuildVersion: 13C100
abort() called

...
```

Comment: You're not alone. It's not a solution, but you can also check this thread for possible workarounds: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/693272

Comment: @lazarevzubov Changing Region worked for me. Thanks. 

Comment: Great to know! I posted it as an answer to make it more visible to other people, who also stumble upon this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a solution, but as a workaround, changing region in System Preferences might help. See also here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/693272